# Django 1.8 Durationfield and time difference

Tags: python, django

```
class Result(models.Model):
    starttime = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    endtime = models.TimeField(blank=True)
    duration = models.DurationField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.duration = self.endtime - self.starttime 
        super(Result, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

What's the correct way of doing this? I get:

- unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subtract standalone times from each other. For example, what would "12pm - 3pm" be?

You can subtract datetimes, since they represent actual points in time. You should probably use DateTimeField instead.